# Gitkraken: Show all files in repo

Tags: git, gitkraken

Is there something like a folder view of a project in Gitkraken? I would imagine so, but cannot find it.

I would imagine that there is a way of navigating all of the files in a repo, and then being able to right-click on a specific file to see its commit history.

Right now if I want to see a file history, I need to know the exact filename, in which case, I do this:

[How to view the git history of a specific file using GitKraken similar to PhpStorm/WebStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45244076/how-to-view-the-git-history-of-a-specific-file-using-gitkraken-similar-to-phpsto?rq=1)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Select the latest commit
2. On the right pane, click the "View all files" button
   [image]